# How to handle UIView rounded corners (using CAShapeLayer) on rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a UITableViewCell containing a UIView. I would like to round all the corners of the UIView when the cell is the only row in the section (i.e. not selected in my implementation). If the cell is selected then I would only like to round the top two corners of the UIView. I am attempting to do this in the custom tableviewcell's layoutSubviews.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.roundedView.layer.mask = nil;

    if (self.sectionSelected) {
        self.maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        self.maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10, 10)].CGPath;
        self.roundedView.layer.mask = self.maskLayer;
    } else {
        self.maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        self.maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10, 10)].CGPath;
        self.roundedView.layer.mask = self.maskLayer;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this method does not work all the time. If I have a the cell selected in portrait (self.sectionSelected = YES). Then deselect (self.sectionSelected = NO). Then rotate to landscape and select the cell again. It displays the cell the size it is suppose to be in portrait. So I believe it is still applying the portrait layer mask and not the landscape one. If I scroll it out of view and then back it in, it updates to the appropriate width. Also of note, I call [self.tableView reloadData]; in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.

Any ideas for avoiding this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Digging further into it. It seems that roundedView.bounds is returning the size of the portrait view at first not the landscape. Why would this be happening?

Comment: it may be worth trying to do this in `setSelected:animated:` if you're using the tableView's own selection logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by simply adding "self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;"